# How to make custom routes survive reboots?

Tags: network, vpn, startup

I use a VPN to connect to the network of my company and add some routes.

After connecting and addding the routes it works just fine. Is there a way to permanently add the routes so that they survive reboots? Currently, I run a shell script to configure them after connecting to the VPN, but I always need to be root to do this.

I'm not experienced with OS X but familiar with UNIX.

Comment: Possibly answered in https://superuser.com/questions/35971/mac-10-6-cisco-vpn-can-i-run-scripts-apps-on-connection

Answer (score 1):

See this script (don't forget to change `ADDRESS/MASK GATEWAY` with your values ):

```
$ sudo mkdir /Library/StartupItems/AddRoute
# cd /Library/StartupItems/AddRoute
$ echo "{
        Description     = \"Add static routing tables\";
        Provides        = (\"AddRoutes\");
        Requires        = (\"Network\");
        OrderPreference = \"None\";
}" > StartupParameters.plist
$ echo "#!/bin/sh

# Set up static routing tables 
. /etc/rc.common

StartService ()
{
        ConsoleMessage "Adding Static Routing Tables"
        sudo route add ADDRESS/MASK GATEWAY
}

StopService ()
{
        return 0
}

RestartService ()
{
        return 0
}

RunService "$1" > AddRoutes
$ sudo chmod 755 AddRoutes
```

Comment: i did that ofc i also used this script: http://nellen.it/blog/2012/01/permanent-static-routes-for-mac-os-x/ which is by looks the same and I get the error unbound variable in line 31 :o